# Copy the first "Object" to all "Object" internal

Tags: java, loops, object

```
public class ObjectA {

   public int ID = 0;
   public string Name = "";
   public ObjectB b = new ObjectB();

}

public class ObjectB {

   public int ID = 0;
   public string Name = "";
   public ObjectA a = new ObjectA();

}
```

how to use like this :

```
ObjectA a = new ObjectA();
ObjectB b = new ObjectB();
a.ID = 1;
a.Name = "Same Name A";
b.ID = 1;
b.Name = "Same Name B";
a.b = b;

String aName = a.b.a.b.a.Name;// == "Same Name A"
```

I want all `a(ObjectA)`'s after `a.b` to be a copy of the first `a`. And all after the `a.b.a` is a copy of the first `b(ObjectB)`.

Example of object:

[image: example of Object]

Also, "loop" and "Exeption" do not happen.

Comment: You can't, this cause `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

Comment: the best solution is what ? a.b.a == null ?

Comment: Why do you design classes like this? **What** and **why** do you want to achieve?

Comment: Something like "entity framework"

Comment: loop detection is best way ?

Comment: What is "Something like entity framework"? You have to be exact or nobody can help you.

Comment: i want create one to one Object for SQLite Table, and select Relation Table into b from a.

Comment: Are your objects JPA entities?

Comment: Do you mean "loop and exception SHOULD not happen"? If so, in what kind of code? The way you have it written now, it sounds like loop and exceptions do not happen in your (unshown) code but should, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a circular reference, you'll have to update one of them after construction, e.g.:

```
class A {
    B b = new B();
}

class B {
    A a;
}

...

A a = new A();
B b = a.b;
b.a = a;
```